# In terminal (bash), should I be in a folder to move it to another?

Tags: terminal, bash, folders

In a directory named World, I've been asked to move a folder within it--South_America--to another folder also within World--North_America. 1. I can't figure out if I should be in South_America or one level up. 2. Wherever it is that I should be, I don't know what code to write. Thanks (I hope)!

Comment: I think you need to look at some Unix tutorials or books as this is a basic part of the file system and if you don't know this there will be many other things that you need to know

Comment: You're right, Mark. I'm doing a learn-as-you-go thing, which is not necessarily the best approach (and leads to no-doubt annoying questions such as mine). All the best, Hope

Comment: It also could lead to costly errors for you

Comment: Costly? Egads. K. Thanks again for the heads up.

Answer (score 2):

Assuming You are in `World` directory (check with `pwd` command) and dir tree looks like:

```
World
 |___ South_America
 |
 |___ North_America
```

You simply do:

```
mv South_America North_America/
```

When You are in `South_America` already, You can:

```
mv ../South_America ../North_America/
```

Comment: Great! (I just have to recall how to move up [I'm brand new at coding] and I'll give it a shot.)

Comment: Whoops. I didn't realize that return = you're done. Anyhow, many thanks and I love your cinema-themed icon.